# GIT Namespaces and HTTP

Tags: git, http, namespaces

I'm struggling with a repository that contains some namespaces.
The following basically shows what I'm trying:

```
$ git init --bare myrepo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in d:/test/myrepo.git/
$ git clone myrepo.git/
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

$ git clone ext::'git --namespace=project-one %s d:/test/myrepo.git' myrepo-project-one
Cloning into 'myrepo-project-one'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

As you can see, this is quite fine :-)
It's also no problem to place this repository on a http server:

```
$ git clone http://server/path/to/myrepo.git tools
Cloning into 'tools'...
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
```

But why does the following go wrong?

```
$ git clone ext::'git --namespace=project-one %s http://server/path/to/myrepo.git' mytest
Cloning into 'mytest'...
fatal: 'http://server/path/to/myrepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

URL checked multiple times, it's exactly the same as used in "git clone http...".
Any hints?

Thanks in advance,
Toka